# Partial Views in MVC and kendo

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and working on partial views with kendo tabstrip. I need to upload the tabs in data after button click on main viewpage. I have 3 partial views, one for the tabstrip and two for the grids in each tab. In my button click controller, I need to call the tabstrip prtialview, send a param

Comment: you can use Ajax and then render a partial view.

Comment: Can u help me out with any sample code if available please.